# Angular - how to temporarily stop watching?

Tags: angularjs

Good day,

I am just learning Angular, so would be glad if you just point on where to look.

I have run into a stupid problem. I have 3 pieces of data on the $scope: width, height, and an array. I have a $watch on that scope, which is creating new (one-diminsional) array of width*height length, when either width or height is changed. This works good.

Now I need to change all three parameters - e.g. set a width and height, and instead of creating empty array to use one filled with data. And the problem I run into is that it seems that the data array is not introduced.

Added to make it clear: what I want, is to overwrite a created array with the data array. E.g. load a saved game.

My understanding is that when I set new width, the angular immediately starts updating data and creates new array with new width and old height. When new height is set it is marked dirty and waits for the next didgest cycle. And when I set a data array it becomes overwritten when the dirty height is processed and new empty array is created.

The question is: is there a way to make sure that all preparations are done before inserting a data array?

PS. This example is simplified and I do understand that I can handle this situation with setting various update markers, etc. I am interested in an "angular way" - is there some kind of event notification that the processing is complete or a function similar to $apply which will guarantee, that all changes are processed?

Thanks!

PPS. Code example (simplified):

```
$scope.w = 15;
$scope.h = 15;
$scope.somearray = [];

$scope.$watch('w*h', function() {
  $scope.somearray = [];
  for (var i=0; i<$scope.w * $scope.h; i++) {
    $scope.somearray.push(0);
  }
});

$scope.update = function() {
  $scope.w = 10; // here the previous watch is fired
  $scope.h = 10; // this value marked as dirty
  $scope.somearray = [1,1,1,1,1]; // this data array becomes overwritten when $watch is fired because of the dirty $scope.h
}
```

Comment: You might be looking for promise ( http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q ). If you are not at ease with promises, you can google it, there is a lot's of good resources

Comment: Thanks for pointing! Start reading and it seems that it really may be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

As far as your array being overwritten, why not initialize the array once:

```
$scope.someArray = [];
```

Then, in the function that is loading your data:

```
var newData = aFunctionThatReturnsArray();
$scope.someArray = newData.slice(0);
```

To watch that the array changed (note the 3rd param to $watch):

```
$scope.$watch('someArray', function(newVal, oldVal) {
}, true;
```

Comment: I have added a code in the original post to show what is going on.

Comment: At this point it seems like a design issue, I would need to see more of your code. How are you loading this data, is it from an ajax call? Are you using $scope.$watch to try and notice when the data has been loaded? If so, then I think $watch is not the solution. The method that does your ajax call should return a promise, and if you assign the promise to a $scope variable, angular will "see" the changes automatically.

Comment: No ajax or other async calls. $watch works correctly. The matter is that the array is heavily processed by angular too (by ngRepeat - new DIV is created for every array element with some extra bindings like ngClick). So in general, what I need is tj set height and width< then wait untill new empty array created and the UI is rendered, and only after that to insert a data array.

Comment: Because of it is just for learning, at the moment I do not want to look at how to optimize rendering or business logick - I want to understand why it doesn't work as expected now and how to bypass it _without_ changing the logick.